# Prepare Task Analysis failing with ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND abc abc:443 in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMphL.png)When I am trying to connect it through the pipeline, SonarQube being in a different Vnet. I also have the Vm image pool in the same Vnet.

Getting Error ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error is request to https://abc failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND abc abc:443 in Azure DevOps

Comment: Could you please clarify if the SonarQube  and self-hosted agent are in the same Vnet? If they are, remote to your self-hosted agent, is it able to ping the Sonarqube `https://lnos-devops-conapp-sonarqube-dev.ambitiousmeadow-06ff8bca.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io`? Try to add host on the machine for a check.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT, yaa I got the solution, when you commented, actually my Service connection was not having the access to that Vnet

Comment: glad to know it's resolved! In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you can post an answer and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!